# Combining csv files in each independent folder and saving the combine file in the independent folder with foldr name

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to loop through a number of folders and concatenate all the .csv files, and output a combined[folder name].csv for EACH folder, via a batch file. For example, for Folder1, the output concatenated file in that folder will be combinedFolder1.csv.How would i go about doing that? i can do it for each individual folder but would like to do batch processing Thanks i have attached a picture and am also adding a code for individual folder

```
joined_files = os.path.join("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Main_folder/folder1/", "*.csv")
joined_list = glob.glob(joined_files)
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, joined_list), ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("folder1.csv",index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, it works perfectly fine with what you want to do:

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd
for i in my_list:
    directory_name="C:/Users/user/Desktop/Main_folder/{0}".format(i)
    os.chdir(directory_name)
    extension = 'csv'
    all_csvs = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_csvs ])
    combined_csv.to_csv( ("{0}.csv".format(i)), index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thanks for you help it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

main_folder = pathlib.Path('data')
data_folders = [d for d in main_folder.iterdir() if d.is_dir()]

for data_folder in data_folders:
    data = [pd.read_csv(csvfile) for csvfile in data_folder.glob('*.csv')]
    pd.concat(data).to_csv(data_folder / f"{data_folder.name}.csv")
```

Folder structure:

```
data
├── Folder1
│   ├── file1.csv
│   ├── file2.csv
│   └── Folder1.csv
└── Folder2
    ├── file1.csv
    ├── file2.csv
    └── Folder2.csv

2 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Thanks for you help it works perfectly